# Como poner 2 animaciones con CSS

Tags: html, css

Estimados estaría agradecido de su ayuda, estoy intentando animar unas barras de progreso, las cuales son 3 elementos hr, una barra gris que representa el 100%, una barra negra que representa el 70% y una barra roja que representa el 80% que vendría siendo el máximo.

La barra negra la animo sin ningún problema, ya que es una animación que va desde un ancho 0 a 70%,
La barra roja me gustaría que fuera con una animación de 0 a 70% para que dure el mismo tiempo que la barra negra y luego animas desde un 70% a un 80%, pero de forma mas lenta, adjunto los estilos actuales, pero aun no consigo que queden bien sincronizadas, no se si me estará faltando algo

```css
.barragris {
  background-color: #AEAEAE;
  border: 0;
  height: 5px;
  width: 100%;
}

.barranegra {
  background-color: #000;
  border: 0;
  height: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 70%;
  animation: animar_negro 1s ease-in;
}

.barraroja {
  background-color: red;
  border: 0;
  height: 5px;
  width: 80%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  animation: animar_negro 1s, animar_rojo 4s
}

@keyframes animar_negro {
  from {
    width: 0;
  }

  to {
    width: 70%;
  }
}

@keyframes animar_rojo {
  from {
    width: 70%;
  }

  to {
    width: 80%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 position-relative">
      <hr class="barragris">
      <hr class="barraroja">
      <hr class="barranegra">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Agrega estas dos líneas en la `barraroja`:

```
animation: animar_negro 1s ease-in 0, animar_rojo 4s linear 1s;
animation-fill-mode: forwards;
```

Básicamente le estoy colocando un retardo de 1 segundo a la animación de la barra roja y la segunda línea hace que la segunda animación comience justo donde se quedó la primera.

```css
.barragris {
  background-color: #AEAEAE;
  border: 0;
  height: 5px;
  width: 100%;
}

.barranegra {
  background-color: #000;
  border: 0;
  height: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 70%;
  animation: animar_negro 1s ease-in;
}

.barraroja {
  background-color: red;
  border: 0;
  height: 5px;
  width: 80%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  animation: animar_negro 1s ease-in 0, animar_rojo 4s linear 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes animar_negro {
  from {
    width: 0;
  }

  to {
    width: 70%;
  }
}

@keyframes animar_rojo {
  from {
    width: 70%;
  }

  to {
    width: 80%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 position-relative">
      <hr class="barragris">
      <hr class="barraroja">
      <hr class="barranegra">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Era justamente lo que me faltaba, muchas gracias Jaime, me sirvió mucho tu respuesta